# How to save faces detected by opencv

Tags: python, opencv, face-detection, face-recognition

I have code that detects a face. All I want to do is save the detected face as a jpg

Here is the code for my program:

```py
import numpy as np
import cv2

detector= cv2.CascadeClassifier('haarcascade_fullbody.xml')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while(True):
    ret, img = cap.read()
    gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = detector.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
    for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)

    cv2.imshow('frame',img)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

How do I save the detected face? Please help!

Comment: There is not *the detected face*. It seems there are multiple. Otherwise, why would you use a for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`detectMultiScale` method returns a list where each elements contains the coordinates and width and height of each face that is detected.

So you can use `cv2.imwrite` and `array slicing`:

```
count = 0
for (x,y,w,h) in faces:
        face = img[y:y+h, x:x+w] #slice the face from the image
        cv2.imwrite(str(count)+'.jpg', face) #save the image
        count+=1
        cv2.rectangle(img,(x,y),(x+w,y+h),(255,0,0),2)
```

Comment: thanks a lot bro it worked!    Also  make change to ```count+```  to ```str(count+)```