# auto detect face only when the human is in motion and take a snapshot with opencv

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition

I'm working on Face recognition project in python, trying to take a snapshot of a human face from an IP cam whenever a human comes in the cam steam. Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
import time

#import the cascade for face detection
face_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(cv2.data.haarcascades + 'haarcascade_frontalface_default.xml')

def TakeSnapshotAndSave():
    video = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://user:password@0.0.0.0:553/Streaming/Channels/401")
    width = 1500
    height = 1080
    dim = (width, height)
    num = 0

while True:
    _, frame = video.read()

    gray = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)

    for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]

    x = 0
    y = 20
    text_color = (0, 255, 0)
    cv2.imwrite('opencv' + str(num) + '.jpg', frame)
    num = num + 1

    frame = cv2.resize(frame, (1500, 1000))
    cv2.imshow("Lodhran Camera", frame)
    k = cv2.waitKey(1)

    if k == ord('q'):
        break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TakeSnapshotAndSave()
```

But it takes the image of the full frame not only the face, while I just want the only faces to be snapped and to be saved like if the frame has 5 humans in the frame at the same time, the out put will be 5 images of the faces of that 5 humans, not the full frame with all humans. Any help with the code will be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: check this. [A similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57055694/how-to-save-faces-detected-by-opencv)

Comment: this is not helpful, by the way thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need to modify your code to make a cropped image for every facebox and then write the cropped image, not a basic frame:

```
for (x, y, w, h) in faces:
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 2)
        roi_gray = gray[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        roi_color = frame[y:y + h, x:x + w]
        cropped_frame = frame[(x, y), (x + w, y + h)]
        cv2.imwrite("some_name.jpg", cropped_frame)
        ...
```